# why EF Database.SqlQuery<T> cannot use entity type for partial selection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a code-first class for EF:

```
public partial class table_test
{
    [Key]
    public int pKey { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a DbContext:

```
public class Test_Context : DbContext
{
    public Test_Context()
         : base("name=Conn")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<table_test> table_test { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query some data from this table:

```
var items = context.table_test.ToArray();
var items2 = context.Database.SqlQuery<table_test>("SELECT * FROM table_test").ToArray();
var items3 = context.Database.SqlQuery<table_test>("SELECT pKey FROM table_test").ToArray();
```

Then I got an error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'UnitTestProject1.table_test'. A member of the type, 'Name', does not
>   have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

[image: EF Database.SqlQuery with entity type]

what's the reason?

Comment: Certainly you cannot just only select single column while the target class has multiple properties. If you want to select only one column, use LINQ `Select` after `ToArray()` or `ToList()` instead.

Comment: you can specify more columns to meet the  property mapping `SELECT pKey, Name FROM table_test`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto query all columns is slower than query columns just I need, and linq to entity `from item in context.table_test select item.pKey` is slower than Database.SqlQuery.

Comment: If you concerned about query performance, then creating a class with single property is more recommended, but IMHO repeating same property in another class sounds redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line produced exception because you're only select single column where EF expects two columns defined by property mapping inside `table_test`, i.e. `pKey` and `Name`:

```
var items3 = context.Database.SqlQuery<table_test>("SELECT pKey FROM table_test").ToArray();
```

If you want to select only `pKey`, just use LINQ `Select()` from existing `items2` array (note: put `using System.Linq;` first):

```
var items2 = context.Database.SqlQuery<table_test>("SELECT * FROM table_test").ToArray();
var items3 = items2.Select(x => x.pKey).ToArray();
```

Comment: so I have to select all columns or create a new type for query?

Comment: Yes, you should either select all columns then using LINQ `Select()` to select certain columns, or create new mapping class which contains only one property (`pKey`).

Answer (score 0):

As [Tetsuya Yamamoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6378815/tetsuya-yamamoto) mentioned in the comments, you can not map to `table_test` class when you only `"SELECT pKey FROM table_test"` because you only have `pKey`.

I do not know the contents of your DB so I will just write a general answer
Change this

```
"SELECT pKey FROM table_test"
```

into

```
"Select * From table_test"
```

But as a general rule you should not use "RAW String while querying the DB" add an abstraction layer on top of that so that it will be easier when or if you ever change propert names in your DTO

Comment: I create a new class type derived from entity type `table_test` in another module, and `SELECT pKey FROM table_test` worked, but in same module that not work, any reason?